# g++ doesn't like template method chaining on template var?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, compiler-construction, g++

I'm trying to compile with *g++* some code previously developed under *Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition*, and it looks like g++ won't let me call a template method on a reference returned by a method of a template variable. I was able to narrow the problem down to the following code:

```
class Inner
{
public:
  template<typename T>
  T get() const
  {
    return static_cast<T>(value_);
  };
private:
  int value_;
};

class Outer
{
public:
  Inner const& get_inner() { return inner_; };
private:
  Inner inner_;
};

template<typename T>
int do_outer(T& val)
{
  return val.get_inner().get<int>();
}

int main()
{
  Outer outer;
  do_outer(outer);
  return 0;
}
```

The code compiles fine under Microsoft's compiler, but g++ throws an error:

```
$ g++ -c main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int do_outer(T&)’:
main.cpp:24: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
main.cpp:24: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘int’
main.cpp:24: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘>’ token
```

where line 24 refers to `return val.get_inner().get<int>();`.

If I make `do_outer` a normal method receiving an `Outer` reference the code compiles. Making `Inner::get()` a normal method also works. And making `Inner::get()` return void and receive a template parameter also works because the *int* specifier below becomes needless, i.e.:

```
class Inner
{
public:
  template<typename T>
  void get(T& val) const
  {
    val = static_cast<T>(value_);
  };
private:
  int value_;
};

...

template<typename T>
int do_outer(T& val)
{
  int i;
  val.get_inner().get(i);
  return i;
}

...
```

(g++ doesn't complaing about the code above.)

Now I'm out of ideas. What's the problem? Is there a problem with gcc/g++? Is there a compliance issue with my code?

The compiler I'm using is:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 4.3.3-5ubuntu4) 4.3.3
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

could you try with?

```
template<typename T>
int do_outer(T& val)
{
  return val.get_inner().template get<int>();
}
```

I don't have access to gcc atm, but I've had similar issues and adding the template keyword always solved them. And it works in VS too.

Comment: This works. See also: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/keyword_template_qualifier.htm

Answer (score 12):

Just to give some background on why the `template` keyword is needed:

```
template<typename T>
int do_outer(T& val)
{
  int i;
  val.get_inner().get<int>(i);
  return i;
}
```

When the compiler sees this function, it does not know what the type of `val` is.  It therefore parses the line `val.get_inner().get(i)` as follows:

**1: `val .`**

The compiler sees the `.` and so can assume that 'val' has class type and the next identifier is the name of a member object or function.

**2. `val . get_inner (`**

`get_inner` is the name of the member and then the compiler sees the `(`.  The only possibility is that `get_inner` is a function name and so this is a function call.  It then parses the parameters until it finds the closing `)`.

**3. `val . get_inner () .`**

As for the first step, it now knows that the return from get_inner must be a class type so it knows that the next identifier is a member object or function.

**4. `val . get_inner () . get <`**

So, what can the `<` possibly mean?  Of course it's the start of template arguments...or maybe it's the less than operator?

We know that `get` can only be an object or a function.  If it is an object then the `<` makes perfect sense as the less than operator.  Furthermore, the standard more or less states that only where the name before the `<` is a `template-name` will it treat the `<` as template arguments (14.2/3):

> After name lookup (3.4) finds that a name is a template-name, if this name is followed by a `<`, the `<` is always taken as the beginning of a template-argument-list and never as a name followed by the less-than operator.

In this case, the compiler has no idea what the type of the expression `val.get_inner()` is and so it cannot lookup `get`.  It more or less assumes then that it's a member object and not a template-name.  '<' is treated as the less than operator and the compiler ends up checking if `get` is less than `int` - hence the error.

So, why do the fixes work?

**Adding the `template` keyword**

Literally we're telling the compiler that the `get` is a template-name and so the `<` operator is treated as the start of a template argument list.

**Removing the template-arguments**

When do_outer doesn't have the template arguments ie: `val . get_inner () . get (` the compiler expects that the member `get` is an object or a function.  The `(` disambiguates between these two and the name is treated as a function.  Later template argument deduction then works out the type of the template parameter.

Comment: +1, one of the more thorough explanation I ever got about this 'quirk'. If only the compiler could be 'smarter' though as always it's much easier said than done... especially considering than it could be a 'value' instead of int ;)

Answer (score -1):

I can't claim to be one of the, oh 10 people on the planet who fully understand C++ templates, but what you're doing here looks fine to me. (It fails with GCC 4.4.1 with the same error, BTW).

Changing `do_outer` to

```
const Inner& inner = val.get_inner();
return inner.get<int>();
```

works with GCC and presumably will also work with Visual C++.

You might consider filing a bug with GCC; either they'll fix it, or it will be closed as INVALID and in the process someone will hopefully explain why what you're doing is not valid code.

A further update and AHA: It turns out it's not actually valid code, GCC just gives a horrible error message. Intel C++ outputs the (actually helpful!) error message:

```
template.cpp(24): error: type name is not allowed
    return val.get_inner().get<int>();
```

Which made me realize the problem. Changing do_inner to

```
  return val.get_inner().template get<int>();
```

the code is accepted by both ICC and GCC.

Comment: That's a waste of their time.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that in the actual code. I'll update the question.

Comment: If this really is valid code, it's not at all a waste of their time. Are you suggesting you know why it's invalid? Please tell us!

Comment: @quant_dev In what way? If it's valid code, which it seems to be, GCC not accepting it is a bug. If it's not valid code, GCC certainly could provide a more informative error message. Either way, GCC has a problem here.

Comment: I think one should file a bug report when one is *certain* that valid code is not being compiled.

You may file a bug report about an unhelpful error message, though.

Comment: After the edit, this discussion doesn't make sense anymore :)