# a case of nested C++ template

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

This piece of code can run correctly in VS2013,and output :
  hello,133
  hello,233
,but in code::blocks(using GCC compiler and in a Ubuntu system),compiler tells me that:

||=== Build: Debug in test_sth (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
In member function ‘void A::say()’:
line 28 error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
In instantiation of ‘void A::say() [with C = B]’:
line 31 required from here
line 28 error: invalid operands of types ‘< unresolved overloaded function type >’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator<’
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 2 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Is there anyone can tell me what's wrong and why ?

line 28 is : this->c.Match<233>();
line 31 is : template struct A< B < int > >;

```
#include "stdio.h"

using namespace std;

template<typename C>
struct A
{
    C c;
    void say();
};

template<typename C>
class B
{
    C name;
    public:
    template<int D>
    void Match()
    {
        printf("hello,%d\n",D);
    }
};

template<typename C>
void A<C>::say()
{
    this->c.Match<233>();
}

template struct A<B<int>>;

int main()
{
    A<B<int>> a1;
    a1.c.Match<133>();
    a1.say();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `this->c.template Match<233>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is taken from http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSQ2R2_8.0.3/com.ibm.xlcpp111.aix.doc/language_ref/keyword_template_qualifier.html:

Use the keyword template as a qualifier to distinguish member templates from other entities. The following example illustrates when you must use template as a qualifier:

```
class A
{
  public:
    template<class T> T function_m() { };
};

template<class U> void function_n(U argument)
{
  char object_x = argument.function_m<char>();  // ill-formed
}
```

In this example, the definition of the variable object_x is ill-formed. The compiler assumes that the symbol < is a less-than operator. In order for the compiler to recognize the template function call, you must add the template qualifier:

```
char object_x = argument.template function_m<char>();
```

Comment: Thanks!And I also found this:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574721/g-doesnt-like-template-method-chaining-on-template-var?rq=1